# Sort a list using awk (idiomatically)

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I'm trying to arrange some entries in the Arch mkinitcpio.conf with awk.
I have come up with a working solution, but honestly it makes me kind of sick, so I wondered, there must be a better way to achieve something like this, right?

Basically there is a line somewhere in the file like this:

```
HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf block filesystems keyboard fsck)
```

and I want to rearrange it so block and keyboard come before autodetect.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
/^\s*HOOKS/ {
    start_list = index ($0, "(" ) + 1
    end_list = index ($0, ")" )
    l = end_list - start_list
    listo = substr($0, start_list, l)
    split(listo, arr, " ")
    j = 1
    for (i in arr)
    {
        if (arr[i] == "keyboard" || arr[i] == "block")
        { }
        else if (arr[i] != "autodetect")
            juck[j++] = arr[i]

        else
        {
            juck[j++] = "keyboard"
            juck[j++] = "block"
            juck[j++] = arr[i]
        }
    }
    for (k in juck)
        print juck[k]
}
```

As per request in the comments: the desired result is a line like:

```
HOOKS=(base udev keyboard block autodetect modconf filesystems fsck)
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Are block, keyboard, and autodetect always going to be present in that list?

Comment: Well, uncertain. I actually don't know how stable the Arch folks keep the format of (default) configs like these. For the purpose of the question, yes.

I guess the better approach would be to just comment out the default line and put the line I want verbatim.

Comment: If `gsub(/\s*\<(keyboard|autodetect)\>\s*/," "); sub(/\<block\>/,"keyboard block autodetect")` isn't all you need then [edit] your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output.

Comment: Well yes, that was basically the kind of thing I was looking for. Thanks a lot. If you care to write it out as a short answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Actually, I spent like fifteen minutes trying to figure out what the escaped angle brackets are for - as far as I understood they are a bash feature to mark word boundaries and apparently they are not strictly necessary for the function of the script, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work, also can be extended for more keywords

```
$ awk -v order="keyboard block autodetect" '
     BEGIN{n=split(order,o)}
     {gsub("[()]",FS)}
     {if($0 ~ FS o[n] FS)
        {for(i=1;i<n;i++)
          if($0 ~ FS o[i] FS)
           {sub(FS o[i] FS, FS)
            sub(FS o[n] FS, FS o[i] FS o[n] FS)}}}
     {sub("= ","=(")
      sub(/ $/,")")}1' hooks_line
```

I didn't add guard against other types of input, but should work with the sample input and regardless of the previous keywords exist or not.

Comment: I appreciate your input very much and I guess I might learn something valuable about awk when I figure out what exactly it is your doing there. But this solution, while not as crude and slightly stupid as mine, appears to me to be slightly more involved than what I was aiming for, which was more the kind of the straightforward one-shot oneliner Ed Morton proposed.